# Not able to read data from MariaDB using Pentaho

Tags: mariadb, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I connected to my database, testeddthe connection and it's working fine
when I run a simple query using the input table transformation I get this error:

```
37:11 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 9.3.0.0-428, build 9.3.0.0-428 from 2022-04-12 04.56.25 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - An error occurred executing SQL: 
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - SELECT * from patient limit 10;
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - 
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - (conn=49) invalid fetch size
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - 
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1776)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery(TableInput.java:242)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:143)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=49) invalid fetch size
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:282)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:336)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.setFetchSize(Statement.java:587)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1754)
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 -   ... 4 more
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection
2022/12/13 11:37:11 - Table input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
```

Comment: Without other code, it's hard to know, but this part of the error may be a clue: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=49) invalid fetch size`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe running the query without the ";" at the end?

Answer (score 0):

This is a driver issue.
Try to change the driver version.